# How to identify Server Socket port behind NAT

Tags: java, tcp, serversocket

I have a server socket in my PC_1 waiting to accept. PC_2 wants to connect that server socket. But PC_1 and PC_2 are behind NAT. So PC_2 doesn't know what is the real port PC_1 listening. I want a mechanism to identify this server socket external port. **I don't want to forward my ports on router(NAT)**. I know this can done through TCP Hole Punching. But I didn't found a way to send a data packet from server socket. So what is the method that I can possibly do this. Thanks!

Comment: is it TCP? or UDP also will do?

Comment: If your router supports UPnP you should check out some UPnP libraries for Java

Comment: @Aniket Yes it is TCP. Not UDP.

Comment: @Aniket I don't like to forward my ports in anyway. Because I want to make this to work in anywhere. There are still routers that doesn't support UPnP.

Comment: I've never seen any possible implementations of TCP Hole punching, and in my view, though theoretically possible, has its practical problems

Comment: I just read the Wikipedia article on TCP hole punching. I feel slightly sick now. You are definitely not going to be able to do this in pure Java; it doesn't support raw IP packet access required for the hackery of sequence numbers, etc.

Comment: @duskwuff I am not asking how to do port forwarding but how to do TCP hole punching(From JAVA).

Answer (score 0):

I see the no forwarding but i dont know if you mean manually or by programming. If you dont mind doing it with a little programming then you should look at [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/).